# how to docker container kill with timeout?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, infinite-loop

i have developed `web IDE` for testing user's code in docker container.
but if user run inifinity loop like `while(true)`, docker container will continuously waste computer resource(memory etc). so i want to kill docker container process after a few seconds. give me for example or reference. Thanks!

Docker Version : 2.0.0.3 (31259)

Comment: I don't think there's an inherent way to do this for docker. But if you're using a bash script for managing this, why not just use bash for timing the lifecycle of the build?

Comment: i use docker container --rm option, and i had used memory limit option, but i can't guess how many memory does `while infinite loop` waste.

Comment: You're looking at solving the wrong problem here. Presumably to run the container you have something working in the background calling docker. Why not use that for timing the lifecycle of a process, then simply kill the container if it reaches a timeout threshold.

Comment: can u recommend some reference for me ? i have not ever use bash scripts.

Comment: How are you calling docker? What is the process calling docker?

Comment: i call docker on nodejs server with `exec` with child process

Comment: anyway, i wil refer bash script for controll proccess timeout option. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then I believe the easiest thing to do is wrap the docker call inside of a JS event and on the event timer running out, kill the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start your process within your container with the [timeout](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) command.

For instance if you are currently starting the process `/somewhere/my_web_ide` in your docker container, you could change that command to:

```sh
timeout --kill-after=3s /somewhere/my_web_ide
```

---

**Note:** the docker image you are using might not have the `timeout` command. To verify that, run the following command: `docker run --rm -it my_docker_image timeout --help`.

Comment: `
stderr unknown flag: --kill-after
See 'docker run --help'.
`
is it problem about timeout command or flag?

Comment: You might have a different version of the timeout command. Run `timeout --help` to see how yours is to be used